# Why do my function returns a dataframe but it cannot attribute the dataframe to a variable in r?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm having a hard time here on writting a simple function which creates a unique code for forest productive areas, using 3 columns of the dataframe. 
Apparently, the function is running fine, but when I try to attribute the result which is returned (which is a dataframe) to a variable, like `result <- cod_uni(dataframe)`, it doesn't work, the console executes the line normally, but the variable isn't even created in Global Environment.
When I run the function whithout attributing the result to a variable it shows the dataframe with the new column with unique codes (as I was expecting).
Here is the function:

```
cod_uni <- function(x, tipo = 'talhao') {
  i <- sapply(x, is.factor)
  x[, i] <- as.character(x[, i])
  
  if (tipo == 'talhao'){
    x$CONCAT_T <- paste(x$ESTADO_FEDERATIVO, 
                   x$CD_HORTO, 
                   x$CD_TALHAO, sep = '_')
  } else if (tipo == 'horto') {
    x$CONCAT_H <- paste(x$ESTADO_FEDERATIVO,
                     x$CD_HORTO,
                     sep = '_')
  } else {
    return(stop('Tipo de código único inválido, escolher entre "horto" ou "talhao"'))
  }
  print(class(x)) #I've put this print to be sure of the variable class - it's returning "data.frame"
  return(x)
}
```

OBS: It doesn't return any error but I've already debbuged the function anyway.

Comment: can you share the dataframe?

Comment: I can shere a pice of the dataframe, but not the whole one because it has some informations about a company that I work for. How can I send to you? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can modify to use `ifelse` instead of `if` and `else`. I don't have the data but if `tipo` is a column in `x` the below code should work. If you have the data I can verify.

```
cod_uni <- function(x, tipo = 'talhao') {
 

 i <- sapply(x, is.factor)
  x[, i] <- as.character(x[, i])
  
x$CONCAT_T <-   ifelse (x$tipo == 'talhao', paste(x$ESTADO_FEDERATIVO, 
                   x$CD_HORTO, 
                   x$CD_TALHAO, sep = '_'),
ifelse(x$tipo == 'horto', paste(x$ESTADO_FEDERATIVO,
                     x$CD_HORTO,
                     sep = '_'),
 'Tipo de código único inválido, escolher entre "horto" ou "talhao"'))
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I've copied the code to stack with an error. It's already edited. It's only a letter in `else if` part (the column should have another name insteads of the same for the first condition tested. You asked about `tipo`, and it's not a column, it's the type of unique code that I want to create. Briefly, my company has a lot of forest gardens, and inside of the forest garden there are a lot of productive areas. With this `tipo` argument you can choose if you want to create a forest garden code or a productive area code.

Comment: Another update: I don't know how and why, when I execute this function on my personal computer it works and I didn't wrote it again, I just copied. Any clue about what is going on?

Comment: Last Update, rs: I don't know how and don't know why, I closed the rstudio and reopenning and the code are running fine right now. I really don't know what happened. I'm sorry to bother you, thaks for trying to help! Really appreciate!

Comment: @caio.valente14 I see you accepted the answer as helpful, should I try to answer these questions in the comments or did it work?

Comment: thanks man, it's running fine here. Thanks a lot for helping me out!